# Spring Integration Kafka xml configration

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-integration, spring-kafka

[image]

Doing migration spring-integration-Kafka 1.1.2 to 3.3.1. In the project, we are using an XML-based Kafka configuration. After changing to the 3.3.1 version. Getting So many errors in the XML file. like `<int-kafka:producer-context id="kafkaProducerContext">` not getting tag. Is there any way to solve this problem?. Or is I need to use java based configuration?

Answer (score 0):

It has had a complete rewrite based on the spring-kafka project since 2.0.

Version 3.3.1 was still a stand-alone extension: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-kafka

The documentation (including XML configuration, which is now simpler) is a chapter in the Spring for Apache Kafka Documentation; it uses version 2.5.7 by default; the latest 2.5.x is currently 2.5.12.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.5.12.RELEASE/reference/html/#spring-integration

`spring-integration-kafka` is now part of the Spring Integration project (since 5.4) and is no longer an extension project.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/kafka.html#kafka